# Как вызвать функцию с аргументами из динамического html?

Tags: javascript

У меня функция генерирует html.

```
function text(massive){
    var text  = '<button oclick='get_func(massive);'></button>';
    document.getElementById("block_to_dynamic_pole_adv").innerHtml = text;
}
```

как мне вызвать функцию `get_func` с аргументом правильно, если сейчас ошибка вылазит , т.к massive - это объект с данными ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если у вас ошибка, то приведите текст ошибки, чтобы было понятнее что нужно исправить. А так у вас ошибка, у вас `oclick`, а должно быть `onclick`. Добавьте `n`

Comment: добавил скрины к описанию

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в неверном способе собирания строки:

внутри одинарных кавычек нельзя использовать неэкранированные одинарные кавычки.

Для экранирования можно воспользоваться обратным слэшем.

Либо использовать разный тип кавычек, например:

```
function text(massive){
    var text  = "<button oclick='get_func(massive);'></button>";
    document.getElementById("block_to_dynamic_pole_adv").innerHtml = text;
}
```

Однако в этом случае и функция `get_func` и переменная `massive` должны быть объявлены глобально.

Если нужно, чтобы передавался параметр функции `text`, то с помощью сбора строк такое можно реализовать только есть параметр можно сериализовать в строку, например:

```
function text(massive){
    var text  = `<button oclick='get_func(${JSON.stringify(massive)});'></button>`;
    document.getElementById("block_to_dynamic_pole_adv").innerHtml = text;
}
```

В противном случае лучше создавать элементы самому:

```
function text(massive){
    var text  = document.createElement('button');
    text.onclick = function(){
        get_func(massive);
    };
    document.getElementById("block_to_dynamic_pole_adv").appendChild(text);
}
```

В ответе использовались методы [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement), [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), а также [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) и [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)